# Find the first quadrant points of the folium

Tags: calculus

Find the first-quadrant points of the folium $x^3 + y^3 = 3xy$ at which the tangent line is either horizontal ($\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$) or vertical (where $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ or $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$).

Comment: I found the derivative of the function which is y'=(y-x^2)/(y^2-x). I do not know what to do from there.